# Android devices: asura, eagle, and ka

Tags: android, google-play, google-tv

In the application statistics page for one of my Android apps on the market I am seeing devices called asura, eagle, and ka. This app is available for Google TV where as my others are not so I assume that these refer to different models of Google TV devices. The question is exactly which device does each of these identifiers refer to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`asura = Sony Internet TV`

`eagle = Sony Internet TV Blu-ray Disc Player`

`ka = Logitech Revue`

You'll also find these designations in `android.os.Build` as BOARD, DEVICE, and HARDWARE in addition to the Market.

Answer (score 2):

adding to Paul's answer:

`cosmo = LG Google TV`

Answer (score 2):

NSGZS7 = [Sony](http://store.sony.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10551&storeId=10151&langId=-1&productId=8198552921666462151) 2nd Generation Set Top Box (non-Blue-Ray)

VAP430 = [Vizio](http://www.vizio.com/streamplayer/overview) Stream player

`Berlin = Marvell ARMADA 1500` (I think this is a reference device)

I am still trying to figure out what `cherrycanyon` is.

Comment: Whatever it is the name is quite imaginative.

Comment: The code name for the NSZ-GS7/GX70 Google TV appears to be "beetle"?